# Unexpected href generated by Html.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionlink

I have this Html.ActionLink in my code:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Up", 
                "GetCategory", 
                "Category", 
                 new { C_ID = CID, D_ID = DID, E_ID = EID, F_ID = FID },
                 new { id = "item-" + ItemID + "-getcategories-" + ItemLevel, 
                       @class = "getCategory" })
```

I want to append a Javascript variable's value to the route dictionary. For this, I used the solution specified in this SO question [ASP.NET MVC 2 Html.ActionLink with JavaScript variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067813/asp-net-mvc-2-html-actionlink-with-javascript-variable)

I attempted to customise [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5071403/1242061) and this is what I have:

```
$(function ()
{
      $('a.getCategory').click(function ()
      {
        .
        .
        .
        var CatID = 0; //Calculate from this.ID
        this.href = this.href + '?Cat_ID=' + CatID;
      });
});
```

**Thing is, the value of `this.href` is not the value generated by Html.ActionLink. Rather, it is the current URL of the page.
My understanding was `this.href` should refer to the ActionLink's href (since `this` refers to the anchor element generated by the ActionLink). What am I doing wrong?**

**EDIT**

*What is even more confusing*: The Html.ActionLink is for one of the tabs (I'm using Jquery UI Tabs). So if I use `.attr('href')` to read the value in the JS function, I get a completely different value:

```
      var AnchorHref = $(this).attr('href');
```

The value of `AnchorHref` is `#ui-tabs-XX` (where XX is a number) - this is a div auto-generated by Jquery UI tabs.

Comment: Can you try your code without the JQuery UI Tabs? Maybe the tabs messing with your hrefs...

Comment: @nemesv: It works fine without the Jquery UI tabs.