# ASP.NET MVC 4 Html.Action with JavaScript variable

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I want to use javascript variable inside MVC Action route values. I referred this [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067813/asp-net-mvc-2-html-actionlink-with-javascript-variable) and the answer given there is working fine.

But i don't want to write an extra javascript function to achieve this. Without writing extra function, Is there any other way to do it. I meant, is there any new added feature in MVC4 for this? As the example in that link is for MVC 2.

```
self.EditUrl = ko.computed(function () {
            return "@Url.Action(Actions.User_Update, Controllers.User, new { Id = self.Id() } )";
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is still the same case with MVC 4. You cannot mix client code and server code. I don't think it would even be possible in the future. Having said that, what you're trying to do is achievable. You can always write the url in a hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" id="userUpdateUrl" value="@Url.Action("User_Update","User")"/>
```

Then use that on your client-side binding:

```
self.EditUrl = ko.computed(function () {
    return $("#userUpdateUrl").val() + "?" + self.Id();
});
```